# Get value of a button to change in CodeIgniter using logic from controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to change the value of a button between login/logout depending on if a session is in progress. The logic works perfectly. The issue I have is sending the actual "login" or "logout" label from the controller (Navigation) to the view (navigation). How do I do this? I have tried sending over TPL but the button is blank (although functions upon being clicked).

Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  // start the session
if(isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
  }

var $TPL = array();

if(isset($_SESSION["accesslevel"])){
  $this->TPL["outPut"] = "Logout";
}
else{
  $this->TPL["outPut"] = "Login";
}




class Navigation extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->template->show('navigation');
    }
}
```

view:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="<?= site_url("/Home"); ?> ">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?= site_url("/Members"); ?> ">Members</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?= site_url("/Admin"); ?> ">Admin</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?= site_url("/Login?act=logout"); ?> "><?php $outPut ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you put "var $TPL" inside your controller class and $this->TPL["outPut"] = "Login"; inside your index method, or in the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is $output accessible in your view?

You need to pass $TPL from controller to your view and Write session code inside constructor.

Constructor :

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Navigation extends CI_Controller {

        private $TPL = array();

        function __construct() {

            parent::__construct();

            if(isset($_SESSION["accesslevel"])){
              $this->TPL["outPut"] = "Logout";
            }
            else{
              $this->TPL["outPut"] = "Login";
            }

        }

        public function index()
        {
            $this->template->show('navigation', $this->TPL);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't check in view if there's a session? if the answer is yes that means that the user is logged and you'll show him the log-out button, otherwise you'll show him the login button.

```
  <?php if ($this->session->userdata('id')){ ?>
    <div class="float-right">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <?php echo anchor('User/user_profile/'.$this->session->userdata('id'), 'My profile', array('class' => 'nav-link')); ?>
        </li>  
        <li class="nav-item">
          <?php echo anchor('User/logout', 'Log out', array('class' => 'nav-link')); ?>
        </li>  
      </ul>
  </div>

  <?php }else{ ?>

    <div class="float-right">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <?php echo anchor('User/login', 'Login', array('class' => 'nav-link')); ?>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <?php echo anchor('User/register', 'Register', array('class' => 'nav-link')); ?>
        </li>      
      </ul>
  </div>

  <?php } ?>
```